# How to add N bases to PyRange object (i.e., shifting PyRanges coordinates)

Tags: python, pyranges

I would like to add `n` (e.g., 1k) bases to a PyRange object (i.e., shifting PyRanges coordinates).
How can I do that?

**Input:**

```py
import pyranges as pr
gr = pr.random(3)

# gr:
# +--------------+-----------+-----------+--------------+
# | Chromosome   |     Start |       End | Strand       |
# | (category)   |   (int32) |   (int32) | (category)   |
# |--------------+-----------+-----------+--------------|
# | chr1         |  10000000 |  20000000 | -            |
# | chr2         |  20000000 |  30000000 | +            |
# | chr22        |  30000000 |  40000000 | -            |
# +--------------+-----------+-----------+--------------+
```

**Desired output:**

```py
# magical command[gr + 1000]:
# +--------------+-----------+-----------+--------------+
# | Chromosome   |     Start |       End | Strand       |
# | (category)   |   (int32) |   (int32) | (category)   |
# |--------------+-----------+-----------+--------------|
# | chr1         |  10001000 |  20001000 | -            |
# | chr2         |  20001000 |  30001000 | +            |
# | chr22        |  30001000 |  40001000 | -            |
# +--------------+-----------+-----------+--------------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `.extend()` method. Starting with your data above, `gr.extend({"3": -10000, "5": 10000})` would generate the following:

```
+--------------+-----------+-----------+--------------+
| Chromosome   |     Start |       End | Strand       |
| (category)   |   (int32) |   (int32) | (category)   |
|--------------+-----------+-----------+--------------|
| chr1         |  10010000 |  20010000 | -            |
| chr2         |  19990000 |  29990000 | +            |
| chr22        |  30010000 |  40010000 | -            |
+--------------+-----------+-----------+--------------+
```

I don't know a way of to apply this "range extension" in a strand specific way (to be able to generate the desired output exactly) but if this is really needed, you should be able to generate 2 `gr` objects, one for each strand, do the manipulation and bring these together.

Comment: OP is not doing anything strand-specific, just adding 1000 to coordinates irrespective of strand. Your answer provides more flexibility than OP needs.